# angular js spring boot and adding one of value of associative array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im new to using angularjs, javascript and Spring boot.
Please help me for this.

I'm trying to show work report rows in attendance page. 
When you click a row on one of the staff on a certain date, it shows the work report rows which shows the reports on what a staff did on a day.

Im trying to add the total workreport hours but I cant't add them and showing it on the browser.

This is how the webpage looks like(There are FROM & TO calendar to select the attendance data).

```
Attendance Page
-----------------
FROM   TO 

Date        |   Staff  |  Clock In   |  Clock Out  | Working Hours 
---------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-01  |   Gwen   |    9:00     |    17:00    |  8

2016-09-01  |   Tom    |    9:00     |    18:00    |  8

2016-09-01  |   Mike   |    9:00     |    17:00    |  7

2016-09-02  |   Gwen   |    9:00     |    17:00    |  7

2016-09-02  |   Tom    |    9:00     |    18:00    |  8

2016-09-02  |   Mike   |    9:00     |    17:00    |  7
```

When you click a row above, it looks like this.

```
Date        |   Staff  |  Clock In   |  Clock Out  | Working Hours 
---------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-01  |   Gwen   |    9:00     |    17:00    |  8
--------------------------------------------------------------

Title       |  Customer | Project |   Progress Rate | Hours
--------------------------------------------------------------

Sales       |    MAC    | iwatch2 |   50            | 5

HM          |  our firm |    SE   |   70            | 2

Consultant  |  our firm |    SE   |   70            | 1
```

And I would want to add hours.             total work report Hours  8

This is the html file and I'm stuck on how to show total work hours for each attendance data's work reports like below.

```
---------------------------
total work hours  | 8
```

And this is the part of HTML.

```
<table st-table="attendanceList" st-safe-src="attendanceList" class="table">
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th st-sort="date">DATE</th>
<th st-sort="staffData.name">STAFF</th>
<th st-sort="clockIn">IN</th>
<th st-sort="clockOut">OUT</th>
<th st-sort="workinghours">WORKHOURS</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat-start="attendance in attendanceList"  class="selectable"
      ng-click="showDetail(attendance.id)" ng-class="attendance.id == selectedAttendanceId ? 'selected' : ''">
<td>{{attendance.date | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}</td>
<td>{{attendance.staffData.name}}</td>
<td>{{attendance.clockIn | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}</td>
<td>{{attendance.clockOut | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}</td>
<td>{{attendance.workinghours | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="attendance.id == selectedAttendanceId">
<td colspan="11">
<h5>WORKREPORT</h5>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>TITLE</th>
<th>CUSTOMER</th>
<th>PROJECT</th>
<th>PROGRESS RATE</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="workreport in workreportMap[attendance.staffDto.id][attendance.date]">
<td>{{workreport.title}}</td>
<td>{{workreport.customer}}</td>
<td>{{workreport.project}}</td>
<td>{{workreport.progress}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>TOTAL HOURS</td> <td>{{hours}}</td>
</tr>            
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the controller. And I'm stuck on adding.

### app.controller('attendanceCtl') -----

```
workbenchApp.controller('attendanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', 'MessagesService', 'attendanceFactory','staffFactory', '・・・otherFatories',
    function($scope, $modal, MessagesService, attendanceFactory, staffFactory, otherFactories) {

    $scope.from = new Date($scope.today.getFullYear(), $scope.today.getMonth()-1, $scope.today.getDate());
    $scope.to = new Date($scope.today.getFullYear(), $scope.today.getMonth(), $scope.today.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);

    $scope.isLoading = true;
    $scope.borderDate = editLockFactory.getBorderDate($scope.today);


    getAttendance();

    function getAttendance() {
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        usSpinnerService.spin('attendanceSpinner');
        attendanceFactory.getfromto($scope.from, $scope.to)
        .success(function(attendanceList) {
            $scope.attendanceList = attendanceList;
            $scope.displayedAttendanceList = angular.copy($scope.attendanceList);

            workreportFactory.get($scope.from, $scope.to)
            .success(function(workreportList) {

                $scope.workreportList = workreportList;

                $scope.workreportMap = {};

                for (var i = 0; i < workreportList.length; i++) {

                    var report = workreportList[i];
                    var keydate = report.date;
                    var totalWorktime = 0;

                    if ($scope.workreportMap[report.staffData.id] == null) {
                        $scope.workreportMap[report.staffData.id] = [];
                    }

                    if (($scope.workreportMap[report.staffData.id][keydate] == null) ) {
                        $scope.workreportMap[report.staffData.id][keydate] = [];

                        $scope.workreportMap[report.staffData.id][keydate].push({
                            title: report.title,
                            customer: report.customer,
                            projects: report.projects,
                            progress: report.progress,
                            hours: hours

                        });

                        totalWorktime += report.hours;


                    }else if($scope.workreportMap[report.staffData.id][keydate].length != 0 ){
                        $scope.workreportMap[report.staffData.id][keydate].length+1;
                        //second push for if there are few data(rows for workreport for a person on a day)
                        $scope.workreportMap[report.staffData.id][keydate].push({
                            title: report.title,
                            customer: report.customer,
                            projects: report.projects,
                            progress: report.progress,
                            hours: hours

                        });

                        totalWorktime += report.hours;
                    }
                }//for END

                stopSpinner();

            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                MessagesService.messages.push({
                    type: 'danger',
                    content: 'ERROR: Status code ' + status
                });
                MessagesService.display = true;
                stopSpinner();
            });

            stopSpinner();
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            MessagesService.messages.push({
                type: 'danger',
                content: 'ERROR: Status code ' + status
            });
            MessagesService.display = true;
            stopSpinner();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable that sums up the hours like "$scope.totalhours" in the following code could be the solution. Then at the end of ng-repeat you can print that value out.

```
$scope.totalhours = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<workreportList.length; i++){

    var workreportList = workreportList; $scope.workreportMap = {};    

    if(workreportMap[attendance.staffData.id] == null){
        workreportMap[staffData.id]= [];
    }
    if(workreportMap[staffData.id][attendance.date] == null){
        workreportMap[staffData.id][attendance.date] = [];
    } else if(workreportMap[staffData.id][attendance.date].length != 0){
        workreportMap[staffData.id][attendance.date].length+1;
    }
    $scope.workreportMap[staffData.id][attendance.date].push({
        title: report.title,
        customer: report.customer,
        projects: report.projects,
        progress: report.progress,
        hours: hours
        });
    $scope.totalhours = $scope.totalhours + hours;
}
```

Note: I also cleared up the two central if statements as they held the same push method twice.

Comment: Jireugi> Hi, thank you for the answer, but I tried and got same hours for all data . Which I think I'll have to map? the added  "hours" for same "date" & "staff" and I'm still stuck. ("Working Hours" is not the same as "hours". "Working Hours" is calculated by subtracting clockin from clockout time.  )

Comment: Would you mind to post the HTML side code with the `ng-repeat`? Maybe there is some subtle problem.

Comment: Jireugi> I've posted the HTML. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask again then. Would you mind posting the `attendanceCtl`? Because at a second look it is not clear where the object `report` comes from. And is it correct that `attendanceList` and `workreportList` reference the same object?

Comment: Sorry, I added the controller.  attendanceList and workreportList is not the same object, attendanceList is for the data which shows the in and out time for each staff who worked on a day. WorkreportList is data list for workpreport list which shows when you click one of the attendanceList.

Comment: Shouldn´t the two lines `hours: hours` not rather be `hours: report.hours`? Also, if you define `totalWorktime` as a local variable via the `var` statement then of course the value gets overwritten in every iteration of the enclosing `for` loop, and moreover for local variables there is no means to access them in the HMTL code. Since you use the `$scope` already why not declare an array `$scope.totalWorktime[staffData.id][attendance.date]` (outside the for loop) and insert the correct value of total worktime per staff and date inside of the loop?